# Xcode 4.0 operating system

Tags: xcode, operating-system

Is it possible to create an operating system in xcode?

Comment: I find this a valid question but it seems you are unfamiliar with how SO works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Xcode has the ability to use GCC and by adding some flags you can create some of the files necessary to create an operating system. The problem comes with the assembly code needed to start the operating system off (can't avoid it). You would have to create a script that runs after the build to use LD to link the assembly files required to actually allow you to create an ELF kernel image (monolithic kernel). I'm going to assume you know the details of writing an OS because you are simply asking if XCode 4 allows you to do it. Personally I wouldn't recommend it, for SIG-OS I have written many and I just do Emacs, GCC, and LD and create a makefile (which makes it easier to manage sometimes).

Answer (score 1):

nice thought, but xCode can only make either Mac OS X application / iOS application based on Mac OS X / iOS libraries.

To write an operating system (e.g. Linux), consider using Linux from Scratch sources & follow their guides.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's also possible to signup here on stack overflow and accept other peoples answers

Xcode 3.1 was an update release of the developer tools for Mac OS X, and was the same         version included with the iPhone SDK. It could target non-Mac OS X platforms, including iPhone    OS 2.0. It included the GCC 4.2 and LLVM GCC 4.2 compilers -- Wikipedia

Comment: I believe this belongs as a comment not an answer....

Comment: It's not necessary to post it as an answer, might as well just post a comment instead and not even bother answering.